# DraftJS - creating a mention entity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Using DraftJS (and DraftJS Mention Plugin), in my Editor component, I am trying to create a mention entity when I receive data from my backend such as: "Hey there, @john12345!" I need to change the slug into a mention entity.

What is the best way to do this?

Can I simply load the data into the Editor, use `this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()`, modify the ContentState object to include an `entityMap` obj + an `entityRanges`obj inside a `block`, then set the editorState once again?

Or should I use the DraftJS API utilities available to me i.e. `createEntity`?

Having trouble finding good examples of this. Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you populating the editor? If you are populating editor with EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Hey there, @john12345!')) editor will automatically create @mention using decorators from DraftJS Mention Plugin.